# Deleting number only elements from an array/string in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, element

I have problem with deleting digit only elements from my string/array (conversion is easy) in bash. The trick is, in the array I have elements containing both digits and other character and I want to keep them.

So for

```
VAR="a2b a22 12b  417 900 600 86400 3600"
```

The output should be

```
"a2b a22 12b"
```

The furthest I could go is:

```
echo ${VAR}# |  sed 's/ [0-9][0-9]*[$ ]/ /g'
```

but it still doesn't solve the problem. I tried to do it in an array, but without "$" and "^" I'm not able to prevent deletion of some parts of "good elements".

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: If your sequence of all digits *always* follows the mixed sequences, you could get by with the regular regex `sed 's/ [^a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]*$//'`, but for a general solution, see John's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with your code.  One is that `[$ ]` will match a literal dollar sign but does, as one might hope, not match the end-of-the-line.  The other is that, while `g` indicates global matching, the matches are not allowed to overlap which would be needed for it to work as you want.

If you have GNU `sed`, then a simple solution is to avoid matching the spaces and instead use `\<` and `\>` to mark word boundaries:

```
$ echo ${VAR} |  sed -E 's/\<[0-9][0-9]*\>/ /g'
a2b a22 12b
```

Alternatively, without the GNU extensions, you can use looping:

```
$ echo ${VAR} |  sed 's/^[0-9][0-9]* / /; :a; s/ [0-9][0-9]* / /g; t a; s/ [0-9][0-9]*$/ /'
a2b a22 12b
```

The code `:a` indicates a label.  The code `t a` indicates a test.  If the previous substitute command did make a substitution, then the `sed` jumps to label `a`.

(The above was tested under GNU sed.  It should work with BSD/OSX sed with only minor adjustments.)

Comment: I couldn't think of a better example to point out the benefits of boundaries in extended regex than this one.